# How to Know Timezone for a record created by user in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

I have a application which is in sharepoint 2010. actually application users works in that application from multiple locations.. and if one user is working for 15 days in IST time (UTC+5:30) and for next 10 days goes to US then he works in CST or EST timezone... so my user changes his timezone as per his location... but now problem is.. when he go to generate his report.. which does not show correct for date time fields.... 
if he is correctly selected IST timezone then all data shows by IST timezone... the EST and CST doest not show correct also user can not segregate his different - 2 timezone data...

actually i have provided a report by asmx webservices.. Please find below code which i have written..

```
              using System;
          using System.Collections;
          using System.Text;
          using System.Data;
          using System.Data.SqlTypes;
          using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
          using System.Security.Principal;
          using System.Net;
          using System.Xml;


          public class SharePointActivities
          {
              [SqlFunction(SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName = "GetActivitiesItemInfo")]
            public static IEnumerable GetActivitiesItems(SqlString url, SqlString listName, SqlString viewName, SqlString Query)
              {
                  DataTable t = new DataTable();
                  WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;

                  WindowsIdentity id = SqlContext.WindowsIdentity;

                  try
                  {
                      ctx = id.Impersonate();

                      WSS.Lists svc = new WSS.Lists();
                      svc.Url = url.ToString();

                      //svc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("krishna", "google@123", "WKS10953");
                      //Or
                      //svc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("krishna", "google@123", "WKS10953");
                      //Or
                      svc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                      //Or
                      //svc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                      //svc.PreAuthenticate = true;
                      //Or
                      //oServices.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("krishna", "google@123", "wks10953");

                      //Query
                      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                      XmlNode query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
                      query.InnerXml = Query.ToString();//"<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Counter\">3</Value></Gt></Where>";

                      //ViewFields
                      XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
                      viewFields.InnerXml = "";// "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";

                      //QueryOptions
                      XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
                      queryOptions.InnerXml = "";

                      XmlNode node = svc.GetListItems(listName.ToString(), viewName.ToString(), query, viewFields, "500000", queryOptions, null);
                      XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(node.OuterXml,
                                                  XmlNodeType.Element, null);
                      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                      ds.ReadXml(rdr);
                      t = ds.Tables[1];
                  }
                  finally
                  {
                      if (ctx != null)
                          ctx.Undo();
                  }

                  return t.Rows;
              }

              public static void GetActivitiesItemInfo(
                                  object obj,
                                  out SqlString ID,
                                  out SqlString Title,
                                  out SqlString RecordDate,
                                  out SqlString ClientVertical,
                                  out SqlString Client,
                                  out SqlString StoreUnits,
                                  out SqlString Process,
                                  out SqlString MainActivity,
                                  out SqlString SubActivity,
                                  out SqlString PeriodStartDate,
                                  out SqlString PeriodEndDate,
                                  out SqlString NoOfPeriod,
                                  out SqlString EntryType,
                                  out SqlString StartTime,
                                  out SqlString StopTime,
                                  out SqlString TimeTaken,
                                  //out SqlString VolumeCount,
                                  //out SqlString InputMode,
                                  //out SqlString Category,
                                  out SqlString Remarks)
              {
                  DataRow r = (DataRow)obj;
                  ID = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_ID"]));
                  Title = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_Title"]));
                  RecordDate = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_RecordDate"]));
                  ClientVertical = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_ClientVertical"]));
                  Client = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_Client"]));
                  StoreUnits = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_StoreUnits"]));
                  Process = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_Process"]));
                  MainActivity = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_MainActivity"]));
                  SubActivity = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_SubActivity"]));
                  PeriodStartDate = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_PeriodStartDate"]));
                  PeriodEndDate = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_PeriodEndDate"]));
                  NoOfPeriod = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_NoOfPeriod"]));
                  EntryType = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_EntryType"]));
                  StartTime = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_StartTime"]));
                  StopTime = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_StopTime"]));
                  TimeTaken = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_TimeTaken"]));
                  //VolumeCount = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_VolumeCount"]));
                  //InputMode = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_InputMode"]));
                  //Category = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_Category"]));
                  Remarks = new SqlString(Convert.ToString(r["ows_Remarks"]));
              }
          }
```

in this code for my report gets parameters start date and end date from Recorddate field.. but if user selected currently IST timezone.. then CST and EST recorded data shows 1 day before which does't work..

so may i know record created timezone and utc value of record data to find in every timezone... or any other solution to find actual date..

Comment: What do you mean "User selects correct time zone"? All date in SharePoint database are stored in UTC date. They are converted to local date during retrieval and they depend on web current locale settings.

Comment: Hi Yevgenic, that i know sharepoint stores data in UTC format..Actually i am generating a report but i am in IST timezone.. but i want to get data from EST,CST timezones users as well.. if i generate a report that always gives me all dates in IST timezone converted but i want only actual time which users has entered..

Comment: Then i guess you need to know user's time zone.

Comment: So how can i know that the record is created in which time zone? beucase user always changes his/here timezone according to his/her location... so this is the main question...  in whcih timezone record is created ??????    ... pls help in this.. this is really urgent for me now...

Comment: I'm not fully understand why do you need in which time zone user created item - all dates are in UTC date - the only thing you need to know in which time zone to display report.

Comment: I have created a report and users will fetch that report by date parameneter.. now what is heppning if i am in IST timezone and want to fetch report for my team who are sitting in different-2 time zones.. so data is not fetching correct.. if my user A was working 5 days for IST timezone and next 5 days in CST timezone and next 5 days for EST timezone.. but still i am in IST timezone.. if i will fetch data for any date (start date and end date parameters) then IST timezone for 5 dates data will come correct with correct recorded but other 10 days does't show in the exact date..  are you clear?

Comment: by the way i am fetching data by webservice by SQL server CLR functions.. you can see my code above then you will understand..

Comment: Probably i do not fully understand you, sorry. Could you please try to convert parameters which you pass to the report to UTC first?

Comment: ohh... you are right.. if i will convert my parameters in utc format then data will come in proper date... but i will have to convert list date column in utc as well.. please check my code then let me know.. how can i convert my parameters in SSRS in utc format and how can i convert my sharepoint list record date column in utc formate to extract right data

Comment: If i not mistaken Lists web service returns dates in sharepoint time zone (you can find it in site actions->site settings->regional settings). You need to read this data using web service(Webs.asmx GetWeb) and then use to it convert list item's date time values to UTC date. You will need to convert ssrs parameters in UTC date from time zone which is used in your report.